# Running java on remote desktop connection

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, sockets, remote-desktop

I'm trying to run selenium/java scripts on remote server using windows remote desktop connection. I'm pretty new to these things.

I got two ideas in my mind one is to use selenium grid and another one is to use sockets for connecting.

I'm running this script for 404 validation over 1000 urls. I have the code that'll run fine in my local machine but due to frequent network issues my organization wants to run on remote server.

I got access for that server on port 3389 and credentials for remote desktop connection.

Now how to do this?

Comment: Install a JDK on the remote machine, copy your jars over, and run it. Not sure what selenium grid, or 'sockets for connecting', has to do with anything.

Comment: So you saying like I need to manually copy jars and do the stuff?

Comment: you need to install on the remote machine what you'd also need to install on your local machine.